# Subtracting columns of dataframes on the basis of index of column names present in lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists (`l1` and `l2`) consisting of required columns of two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`) that I would like to apply operation upon.

One list has all required columns ending with an `_x` and the other with an `_y`.

I would like to subtract the values of these columns by index, for instance,

```
df_final['first_col_sub'] = first element of l2 - first element of l1
df_final['second_col_sub'] = second element of l2 - second element of l1 and so on
```

Actually both of the dataframes have the same column headers and I cannot directly use the column headers to perform the operation which is why I added `_x` and `_y` in the column headers so that it may help to do the subtraction.

For example,

```
df1,

    1_x | 2_x | 3_x | 4_x | 5_x ...
     1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5


df2,
    1_y | 2_y | 3_y | 4_y | 5_y ...
     5  |  4  |  3  |  2  |  1



df_final,
    first_col_sub | first_col_sub | first_col_sub | first_col_sub | first_col_sub ...
           4      |       2       |        0      |      -2       |       -4
```

How may I achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

(If there is anything unclear please let me know.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If same number of rows and same number of columns with matched values before `_` use:

```
l1 = ['1_x','2_x'...]
l2 = ['1_y','2_y'...]
df2[l2].sub(df1[l1].to_numpy())
```

Or better is remove `_x` and `_y` for match values before `_` in subtract:

```
f = lambda x: x[:-2]
df2[l2].rename(columns=f).sub(df1[l1].rename(columns=f))
```

Also is possible filter by ending `y` and `x` columns in [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
f = lambda x: x[:-2]
df2.filter(regex='y$').rename(columns=f).sub(df1.filter(regex='x$').rename(columns=f))
```

Or:

```
df22 = df2.filter(regex='y$')
df11 = df1.filter(regex='x$')
df22.columns = df22.columns.str[:-2]
df11.columns = df11.columns.str[:-2]

df22.sub(df11)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to retain the columns ending _y and _x of the list in the final df. How may I achieve that?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - hmmm, so it means expected output is different? If yes, is possible change it like you need?

Comment: @royalewithcheese - Or need finally e.g. `df  = pd.concat([df1, df2, df22.sub(df11)], axis=1)`  ?

Comment: yeah, it will have columns from df1, followed by columns of df2 and then columns of df_final

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract pandas dataframes directly:

```
df_final = df2 - df1
```

Or based on index names:

```
for x in df_x.columns:
    base = x[0:-2]
    if base + '_y' in df_y.columns:
        df_f[base + '_final'] = df_x[x] - df_y[base + '_y']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thing is I have other columns ending with _x and _y, therefore, I have to rely on lists.